# elastic4s: score stays at 1 with rawQuery

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

We're using elastic4s for ElasticSearch 2.2.0. A number of queries is stored as JSON on disk and used as *rawQuery* via the elastic4s driver. The score in the result differs between the query being submitted via command line or the elastic4s driver. The elastic4s driver always returns score of 1 for all results, while the command line execution yields two different scores (for different data types).

The code for elastic4s:

```
   val searchResult = client.execute {
      search in indexName types(product, company, orga, "User", "Workplace") rawQuery preparedQuery sourceInclude(preparedSourceField:_*) sort {sortDefintions:_*} start start limit limit 
    }.await
```

Note that I removed anything but `rawQuery preparedQuery` and it didn't change the score **1**. The full query via the command line is quite long:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "${search}",
                        "fields": [
                            "name",
                            "abbreviation",
                            "articleNumberManufacturer",
                            "productLine",
                            "productTitle^10",
                            "productSubtitle",
                            "productDescription",
                            "manufacturerRef.name",
                            "props"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "or": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "type": {
                                            "value": "Product"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "publishState": "published"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "must_not": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "productType": "MASTER"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "deleted": true
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is almost `preparedQuery` but for the replacement of `$search` with the search query. The elastic search REST client returns a score of **3.075806** for the matches.

Comment: When you say result score, is this the per-item score?
What does "The elastic search REST client returns a score of 3.075806 for the matches." mean?

Comment: Do you get the exact same results through elastic4s driver and through REST?

Comment: @James the elastic search REST client means querying elastic search via curl directly. Val the score is different, 1 for elastic4s and 3.075806 for the curl REST query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elastic4s `rawQuery` will wrap your rawQuery-JSON in another query object.

it's like you would query for

```
{ "query": { "query": {     
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "${search}",
...
```

just remove your wrapping *"query"* from you JSON and the response will show varying scores.

Alternatively you can try to use `extraSource` instead of `rawQuery`, like described in elastic4s docu. although it didn't work for me at all:

ErrorMessage:
value extraSource is not a member of com.sksamuel.elastic4s.SearchDefinition